# Mocking of methods present the in the main method

Tags: java, spring, oop, mocking, powermockito

I am new to Unit testing and using Mockito framework.

I have a Java class and have the main() method in it. In my Main() method I have several other methods that I need to Unit test.

**This is my class to test**

```
public class client{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
         Ip ip  =  createIpEvent();
   .
   .
   .
   }
   private static Ip createIpEvent(){
    Ip ip = new Ip();
    ip.setters(); // various setters
    return ip;
    }
 }
```

**This is my Test class that I am making.**

```
public class clientTest{
  
 client clientMock = mock(client.class);
 
 @Test
 public void testCreateIpEvent(){
  Ip ip = new Ip();

  //setters....
  try(MockedStatic<client> utils = Mockito.mockStatic(client.class)){
        utils.when(() -> client.main()....)
    //here I am only able to access the main() method and not the method createIpEvent()

 }


}
```

Please some one help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `createIpEvent()` method is private. Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in) to get a better understanding of access specifiers.

Comment: actually I have found something that by using powermock we can mock the static and private methods, but I am not able to get it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).